# Is CAS version 3.4.3.1 compatible with WAS 9.0 and Java 8

Tags: java, cas, was

We had CAS version 3.4.3.1 installed on WAS 7 and Java 6. Migrated it to WAS 9 and Java 8. Having issues and want to check if CAS version is compatible with Java 8 and WAS 9

Answer (score 1):

> want to check if CAS version is compatible with Java 8

CAS 3.x was only ever compiled and released on JDK 6. It's possible it can run on later JDK versions, but there is no verifiable test to guarantee this.

> and WAS 9

Likewise, there is no verifiable test to guarantee this and this was never tested by the project. The most common server environment is Apache Tomcat.

Note that CAS 3.x is EOL.